# Xamarin Mac Keyboard Input in different Windows

Tags: c#, cocoa, xamarin.mac

i have made my first program for mac, a simple Terminal emulation with Xamarin Mac Cocoa.
To draw the Terminal i use XiaSharp.
To get the Input i use:

```cs
NSEvent.AddLocalMonitorForEventsMatchingMask(NSEventMask.KeyDown, KeyboardEventHandler);

private NSEvent KeyboardEventHandler(NSEvent keyEvent)
        {
            //FOR GL KEY

            if (keyEvent.KeyCode == 51) CSTSocket.SendByte(8); //Back
            else if (keyEvent.KeyCode == 36|| keyEvent.KeyCode == 76) CSTSocket.SendByte(13); //Enter
            else if (keyEvent.KeyCode == 49) CSTSocket.SendByte(32); //Space
            else if (keyEvent.KeyCode == 123) CSTSocket.SendByte(8); //Arrow Left
            else if (keyEvent.KeyCode == 126) CSTSocket.SendByte(11); //Arrow Up
            else if (keyEvent.KeyCode == 124) CSTSocket.SendByte(12); //Arrow Right
            else if (keyEvent.KeyCode == 125) CSTSocket.SendByte(22); //Arrow Down
        }
```

This works well with one Window, but if i add more Windows with:

```cs
[Export("newWindow:")]
        void NewDocument(NSObject sender)
        {
            // Get new window
            var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
            var controller = storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier("MainWindow") as NSWindowController;

            // Display
            controller.ShowWindow(this);

            // Set the title
            controller.Window.Title = (++WindowCount == 1) ? "Watermelon" : string.Format("Watermelon {0}", WindowCount);
        }
```

Problem: I type in every created Window at the same Time.

Is there an Event where i can determine which window is active, or is there another Keyboard event i have to use ?

Any advice is appreciated

Example Picture:
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEXQD.png)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself:

In ViewController.cs you can get a boolean value if window has input focus:

```cs
this.View.Windows.IsKeyWindow
```